# how to make changeable parameter url in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

for example: 
here are some names. 
-mujib 
-amjed  
-anees

when if some one click on mujib the url should remind old and the parameter should change when some body click on amjed then the url parameter should change to http://jobme.af/amjed.

http://jobme.af/mujib

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('jobme.af/amjed/{parameter}', 'your-action');
```

see also https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-parameters